# How to get up to speed in a new web development job when there's no documentation?

Tags: new-job, relationships, web

I just arrived in a company to code in PHP and MySQL and I'm trying to get familiar with the codebase.

I see the source code of the website and there is no documentation, no comments above the function names and no documentation for the database.
Well, I know the PHP language, so I could read the entire index.php file, the entire .htaccess and read all the source code of the company by myself, but it's really very long and it will take a very very long time. I can also ask my colleagues when I want to know a thing.

How should I do this?
Read the entire source code already written of the source code of the website of the company (but it could take several days or month to understand it in a big project)? Or may I ask my colleagues each time I need information?

PS: This is not an existing framework. This is a 100% home-made source code.

Comment: So basically you are saying there is no documentation whatsoever of the website of your company?

Comment: Yes, I confirm there is not any documentation

Comment: Have you let your boss know about these issues?  If so, what did they say?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Divided and Disorganized Development Team](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126730/a-divided-and-disorganized-development-team)

Comment: Welcome new user.  Please move the question to software engineering.   You are asking "how to work with code" given a specific code problem.  Really it has nothing to do with this site.

Comment: You say it would take several days or a month to read the source code.  If you really can read and understand the source code in a month or less, that's great!  Just do that.  That's a very small project.

Comment: You don't. You start working on bugs and features. When you see some code you do not understand run the blame on it and check the tickets this block was introduced and why. If it is still does not make sense talk to the person who introduced or domain experts as well as business people who can guide you about the expected functionality.

Comment: You don't. You start working on bugs and features. When you see some code you do not understand run the blame on it and check the tickets this block was introduced and why. If it is still does not make sense talk to the person who introduced or domain experts as well as business people who can guide you about the expected functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you **do both**: start getting familiar with the code and database structure of the website and consider politely asking your more experienced coworkers for insights or clarifications if there are parts that are not so clear (or that are urgent for your current tasks).

Think of it this way. You would eventually want to be an 'expert' on that webpage and it's design, so sooner or later you will have to actually read all the code (so it's better to do it sooner).

Now, realistically speaking, if there is some bug to fix or specific part to upgrade, or specially obscure segment of code, it's perfectly fine to ask for assistance or clarification from your coworkers, so your learning process is faster.

However, do *not* rely solely on asking your coworkers, as that may eventually get tedious for them or sometimes they might no have the time to spare; try to find the answers on your own before considering checking with others.